# How to make a FactoryGirl.create affect another record's attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

In a webshop application normally after a **booking** of a product the **bookings_controller** create action does an `order.save` which in turn activates the necessary before_save method `order.sum_of_all_bookings`.

When building a RSpec test for an admin viewing a list of orders, making a booking doesn't change the total of an order. The indexing does work in the browser.

```ruby
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature 'Admin can oversee orders' do
  let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, :admin) }
  let(:customer) { FactoryGirl.create( :user ) }
  let!(:order_1) { FactoryGirl.create( :order, customer: customer ) }
  let!(:booking_1) { FactoryGirl.create( :booking,  product_name: 'Honingpot', 
                                                    product_quantity: 1, 
                                                    product_price: '5,00', 
                                                    order: order_1 ) }
  let!(:order_2) { FactoryGirl.create( :order, customer: customer ) }
  let!(:booking_2) { FactoryGirl.create( :booking,  product_name: 'Streekpakket',
                                                    product_quantity: 2, 
                                                    product_price: '10,00', 
                                                    order: order_2 ) }


  before do
    order_1.sum_all_bookings
    order_2.sum_all_bookings
    login_as(admin)
    visit orders_path
  end

  scenario 'with success' do
    within('table#paid') do
      expect(page).to have_content '5,00'
      expect(page).to have_content '10,00'
    end
  end
end
```

Before block doesn't work.

Neither does the factory girl after create:

```ruby
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :booking do
    product_name 'Honingpot'
    product_quantity '1'
    product_price '3,99'
    order
    after(:create) { |booking| booking.order.save } # booking.order.sum_all_bookings, also not working
  end
end
```

RSpec prints the bookings being in the order, yet the order total being unchanged.

How to make the order sum the bookings?

Or more generally:

How to make a `FactoryGirl.create` affect another record's attribute?

Comment: Can you please post code of `sum_all_bookings ` and before save callback? Order class and Booking class code?

Comment: yo mate, how did the refactor go?

Comment: I have to revise my join model. Thanks for your effort, but I pretty much read  about these these solutions already.

Answer (score 2):

## Cleaning up your specs

First off, you have too much factory configuration in your spec. [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) is here to move the creation and setup *away* from your specs.

This will not directly solve your problem, but these steps will make your testing proccess cleaner, simpler and faster.

### 1. Faker Gem

To get started with the revamp go ahead and add the [faker gem](https://github.com/stympy/faker) so you can easily generate useful, random data for your factories.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :booking do
    product_name { Faker::Commerce.product_name }
    product_quantity { Faker::Number.number(2) }
    product_price Faker::Number.decimal(2)

    order
  end
end
```

There you go, some solid booking factories ready to be used.

### 2. Traits

They are a great way to adapt your factories for certain scenarios. Definitely [read more about them in the docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits).

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :order do 
    customer

    trait :with_bookings do 
      after(:create) do |order|
        order.bookings << create_list(:booking, 2)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So now you can easily create an order with or without bookings:

```
let(:order_with_bookings) { create(:order, :with_bookings) }
```

### 3. Cleaner syntax

You can leave out the `FactoryGirl` syntax, simply `create(:order)` will do. After these steps you should have a much cleaner test environment.

## Solving the callback problem

As I understand it, you set up your callback like this:

```
class Order
  has_many :bookings

  before_save :update_order_cache

  def update_order_cache
    # calculation of the total bookings sum 
  end
end

class Booking
  belongs_to :order
end
```

But you should do it the other way round, after the product has been created or updated, the callback on the order should be triggered:

```
class Order
  has_many :bookings

  def update_order_cache
    # calculation of the total bookings sum 
  end
end

class Booking
  belongs_to :order

  after_save do
    order.update_order_cache
  end
end
```

You can also add a default value to the sum if that field should never be blank.

```
validates :sum_field, presence: true, default: '0.0'
```

This should wrap this up for you. Cheers!

Comment: Nothing of what you say works for me. Your last solution of the callback doesn't change the spec, and doesn't work for update and destroy in my application. The first one I don't want, I want to be expressive in what I do and define my bookings myself. Helps me to understand. Then the traits thing becomes a problem too, because bookings need to be unique. I guess I could build a sequence. Generally my app seems to have a problem with the bookings being a has many object while also being a join table object. Somehow doesn't activate the sum_all_bookings on the order parent.

Comment: 1) you can add additional callbacks to catch those cases: `after_update`, etc... My message stands, switch it to the bookings. 2) by default it generates random data, but you can still be specific and define data in the spec. In this case it makes sense to define the `product price` and `order`, but the other fields? Not really. And 3) How do the traits raise a uniqueness issue?

Comment: And after you set up your callbacks correctly in the models, you should not have to worry about them anymore. Especially not in tests that have nothing to do with the callbacks.

Comment: switch the callbacks to the products, not the bookings*

Comment: The whole thing is the bookings should work even if the product has been deleted. A booking stays saved. It is getting too complex. The `has_many :bookings` in the order is somehow not working like I thought. Thinking I am going to build the whole app again using member actions and not a has many through join_table.

Comment: Why would you delete all your progress? Your issue is definitely solvable without a complete rewrite... And my answer didn't solve your problem?

Comment: There is a problem with the bookings saving onto the order generally. I make or delete bookings on an order. It's not attaching or detaching, even if I know the order id is there. Really weird. It seems to be more about this. You're right I shouldn't delete all my progress...

Comment: And I made a dumb mistake. I was talking about bookings all along, but in my callback solution I somehow switched to products... Maybe that caused the confusion? I updated my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128199/discussion-between-code-monky-and-thechamp).